# How to solve error "Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'ProtocolVersion'."?

Tags: ssl

I am trying to hit the endpoint "https://---.cloudstoragesecapp.com/api/token" using username and password, but i am getting an exception with message "Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'ProtocolVersion'." This error only occurs in localhost where as it works fine after deployment. Could somebody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint name and issue suggest you are trying to connect to a remote server that’s using a TLS set to "Modern" compatibility.

This error usually happens because your client is running from an older OS version (e.g Windows 10) and your server (the one you are trying to connect), TLS/SSL Profile might be set to “Modern” compatibility level (which works great but only for connecting from clients like Windows 11).

Try setting your server’s TLS/SSL Profile to “Intermediate” compatibility level, this way you can still connect with older OS clients.

Comment: I am using .net8 and windows server2019 and I have the same issue (I am using HtmlDocument.LoadWebPageAsync). How can I set my server TLS/SSL profile to "Intermediate"?

Comment: It varies according to the type of OS the server you are to connect to. For example, Synology has it under Control Panel -> Security -> Advanced tab. Not sure about Windows, Ubuntu, etc though.